# Stopping emails sent due to error/validation firing in Case trigger

Tags: email, validation, case, email2case

Currently we have a validation rule on Case to stop spam emails from creating cases. When this validation fires, it stops the case from being created but an email notification is delivered to the Automated Case User. Is there a way to stop the error notification from being sent?

Please let me know in case any other details are needed. Thanks in advance!